# Destroy/hide twitter bootstrap tooltips when using pjax

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, dom, twitter-bootstrap, pjax

I've had some issues with the twitter bootstrap tooltips [not being removed from the DOM](https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/issues/2298) element when using pjax on a Rails app.  For example, when I mouseover an element with a tooltip, then click a link to another page, the tooltip is frozen.  My current solution to removing the tooltips is as follows:

```
App.Utils.Tooltip = {

  triggerAll: function(element) {
    if (element.data('tooltip-loaded') == true) { return; }
    element.data('tooltip-loaded', true).tooltip().trigger('mouseover');
  },

  destroyAll: function() {
    var tooltips = ($('[rel=tooltip]').get());

    $.each(tooltips, function() {
      $(this).tooltip('destroy');
     });
  }

};

$(document).on('mouseover', '[rel=tooltip]', function() {
  App.Utils.Tooltip.triggerAll($(this));
});

$(document).on('pjax:beforeSend', function() {
  App.Utils.Tooltip.destroyAll();
});
```

Is there a more efficient / effective way to do this?

Comment: Seems like an appropriate method to me

Answer (score 1):

The tooltip plugin stops you from instantiating it twice so the check is unnecessary you can simplify your code to the following.

```
App.Utils.Tooltip = {
  triggerAll: function(element) {
    element.tooltip('show');
  },
  destroyAll: function() {
    $('[rel=tooltip]').tooltip('destroy');
  }
};
```